# Why does database recovery take so long?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, recovery

On my SQL Server 2012 x64 Std instance I had a large transaction fail due to the transaction log filling up yesterday, it couldn't be rolled back and SQL Server has restarted the specific DB to perform recovery.

The DB is around 750GB with the tlog hitting 170GB (very large ETL job was running). The job was only running for a few hours but the recovery so far has taken >24 hours (70% complete, on phase 3 of 3).

What I can't understand it why it's taking so long? There doesn't seem to be any pressure on the disks, `sys.dm_exec_requests` shows it waiting on `PAGEIOLATCH_EX/SH`, which I'd expect. I could've restored the entire DB in this time...

If anyone can shed any light, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As requested, getting the output of the error log:

```
Recovery of database 'MyDB' (6) is 77% complete (approximately 28100 seconds remain). Phase 3 of 3. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
Recovery of database 'MyDB' (6) is 77% complete (approximately 28095 seconds remain). Phase 3 of 3. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
Recovery of database 'MyDB' (6) is 77% complete (approximately 28099 seconds remain). Phase 3 of 3. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
Recovery of database 'MyDB' (6) is 77% complete (approximately 28102 seconds remain). Phase 3 of 3. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
Recovery of database 'MyDB' (6) is 77% complete (approximately 28097 seconds remain). Phase 3 of 3. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Also, the `sys.dm_exec_requests`info you're after:

```
session_id  command status  percent_complete
35  DB STARTUP  background  86.06061
```

IFI and "Perform volume maintenance tasks" enabled/granted.

Comment: After recovery completes can you check how many VLFs you have?

Comment: Will do, but I fairly recently sorted these out as it is such a big tlog. I believe this only impacts phase 1 on recovery anyway (I'm on phase 3 now).

Comment: @RemusRusanu as promised: there are 825 VLFs in this DB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I had a large transaction fail due to the transaction log filling up yesterday, it couldn't be rolled back and SQL Server has restarted the specific DB to perform recovery.

This is not totally correct when a transaction starts in SQL Server it reserves space in transaction log in case the transaction has to rollback. From [Transaction Log architecture BOL doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835093(v=sql.110).aspx)

> Rollback operations are also logged. Each transaction reserves space
>   on the transaction log to make sure that enough log space exists to
>   support a rollback that is caused by either an explicit rollback
>   statement or if an error is encountered. The amount of space reserved
>   depends on the operations performed in the transaction, but generally
>   it is equal to the amount of space used to log each operation. This
>   reserved space is freed when the transaction is completed

So I guess you can understand now.

> What I can't understand it why it's taking so long?

Query rollback operation is `mostly single threaded` while when same query executes it can use parallelism/multiple threads to perform same operation making it very fast as compared to the rollback. I suggest you read What [Bob Dorr has to say about rollback taking long time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/09/12/sql-server-2000-2005-2008-recoveryrollback-taking-longer-than-expected/). To get more insight about what occurs when rollback is in progress please read [This article](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/happens-issue-kill/). Restarting SQL Server service is not going to help much, after restart the rollbak process had to start again. You have to wait and let the rollback process complete.

You can also use sys.dm_exec_requests to track your rollback.

```
select    
session_id,     
command,     
status,     
percent_complete    
from sys.dm_exec_requests    
where command IN ('killed/rollback','rollback','db_startup')
```

The other reason which Remus mentioned is [too many VLF's](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/high-virtual-log-file-vlf-count/). If you have to many VLF's recovery can take lot of time. Also other factor that can delay recovery is if SQL Server service account does not have [`Perform Volume maintenacce task right or instant file initialization`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779312(v=ws.10).aspx). You can use [this link](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2013/10/30/check-for-instant-file-initialization.aspx) to check if IFI is present or not.

**EDIT:**

From The output you posted

```
session_id  command status  percent_complete
35  DB STARTUP  background  86.06061
```

The startup process is `86 % complete.` Just keep monitoring it, eventually it will complete. Also as stated rollback process can get blocked and can incur waits so keep monitoring that as well.

> 2012 x64 Standard SP2

You have standard edition which cannot take advantage of [fast recovery](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/lock-logging-and-fast-recovery/) which is present in enterprise edition. With fast recovery database can come online after second phase of recovery(the redo phase) however it is alwasy not the case so please read the article. As an additional reading you can read [When is fast recovery used](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/fast-recovery-used/). Standard edition limitation could be one more reason why it is taking database time to come online.

> One other thing, the rollback session (35) is itself blocking another system process from performing CHECKPOINT

Yes it can and you cannot do anything as you have no control over system process in terms you cannot kill it.

Comment: Many thanks for the response, I don't suppose it makes any difference but the *transaction* is not rolling back, the database is recovering (I realise that's what the recovery is doing though). The session I'm tracking on `sys.dm_exec_requests` is DB_STARTUP.

Comment: Can you run `sp_readerrorlog` command and look into the logs specific to your database. Please add that into the question. The logs would help me in giving you better response.

Comment: No rows. Updated question with error log as requested.

Comment: Definitely not blocked. `select blocking_session_id from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id=35` returns `0`

Comment: Out of curiosity do you have enterprise or standard editionor any other edition. What is outpupt of `select @@Version`

Comment: Thanks for the update, I think you're right, although I think the ERRORLOG of 77% complete is more accurate. One other thing, the rollback session (`35`) is itself blocking another system process from performing `CHECKPOINT` - I'm guessing that won't cause an issue? You've answered my initial "why is it taking so long" question anyway. Edit - 2012 x64 Standard SP2