# Very slow SQL Server database recovery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, recovery

We have a very large DB (6TB) that is taking a long time in recovery, after we rebooted the server.

After doing some research we understand that it is because of the large number of VLFs. Right now, it is a waiting game.

In the SQL Server log, we see that the ETA is 24 hours! This is for the first of the three phases!

We have announced everyone that DB will be available in 24 hours, not knowing there are 2 more phases.

Does anyone know, how long the other 2 phases take? Just a ballbark number would do. By any chance are the next 2 phases shorter than the first one?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what we found:

Even though the SQL LOG claimed an ETA of 24 hours, the DB recovered in 12 hours. So the numbers were grossly over-estimated.

Even though SQL LOG was showing percentage recovery completion, it didn't go all the way up to 100%. At around 27%, SQL log said everything okay and recovery complete.

In our case 2 things caused this issue:

1. Large number of VLFs (697 in our case, for a 70GB log. Although, 697 doesn't seem that large to me)
2. In our case 800,000+ transactions were required to roll forward. So that could have contributed significantly too.

The answer to my original question: It seems the phase 1 is the slowest; 2 and 3 went very quickly.

We got an answer from Microsoft. Here are some notes from them:

> There are 3 phases of the recovery process
>
> **Analysis:** In this phase the transaction log is analyzed and records the information about the last checkpoint and creates on Dirty Page Table, this might capture all the dirty pages details.
>
> **Redo:** It’s a roll forward phase. When this phase completes database becomes online so the database was online
>
> **Undo:** It’s rollback phase. It holds the list of the active transaction from the analysis phase basically undoing the transactions.
>
> In Summary:
>   This is normal for SQL Server when there is an unexpected shutdown when there is an execution of long running transaction. A database goes through 3 phases of recovery and then comes online – Enterprise edition allows the database to come online after second phase.  This means that there is a rollback running at the moment; need to wait for this to complete. Let the server finish the rollback process if a long-running transaction was terminated. Terminating the server process during the rollback of long-running transaction results in long recovery time.

This might look counteractive; I'm going to post it anyway. If I have to refer in the future, or for folks who might be a victim of this scenario.

It took 13 hours to recover the db. Here are the rough numbers.

Total Recovery time (about 13 hours) = 11 hours analysis + 1 hour redo + 0 hours undo

Comment: The VLFs didn't cause the issue, 697 on a 70 GB log  is 102 MB/VLF which is on the small side - it's the 800k redo transactions that were the main issue.

Comment: Sean, I agree with you. We opened a ticket with MS, and they were quite adamant on the VLF part. We were told that anything over 350 is high. But i feel the roll forward had a higher stake.

Comment: 697 VLF should really not be the issue, the 2nd point is what caused long recovery time and again 1st phase is analysis which should not take much the redo and undo(2nd and 3rd phase)  is what should take time

Answer (score 2):

You cannot know that in advance the information would be printed in errorlog after the phases complete, however you can know how much total time it would take for recovery. See [How to: Check Estimate Completion Time for Backup/Restore Process](http://www.wisdom-soup.com/blog/tools-tools-tips-and-tricks/to-check-estimate-completion-time-backuprestore-process/)

```
SELECT 
    command
    , s.text
    , start_time
    , percent_complete
    , CAST(((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate()))/3600) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
        + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%3600)/60 as varchar) + 'min, '
        + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%60) as varchar) + ' sec' as running_time
    , CAST((estimated_completion_time/3600000) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
        + CAST((estimated_completion_time %3600000)/60000 as varchar) + 'min, '
        + CAST((estimated_completion_time %60000)/1000 as varchar) + ' sec' as est_time_to_go
    , dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as est_completion_time
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_requests r
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s
WHERE 
    r.session_id=xxx--session_id of task doing recovery.
```

I do not have resources to test it now, please let me know if it works or else I will remove it.

You can also try using query mentioned in [Determining how long a database will be IN RECOVERY (SQL Server 2008)](http://timlaqua.com/2009/09/determining-how-long-a-database-will-be-in-recovery-sql-server-2008/) by Tim Laqua. It is actually reading from errorlog

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(64) = 'databasename'

DECLARE @ErrorLog AS TABLE([LogDate] CHAR(24), [ProcessInfo] VARCHAR(64), [TEXT] VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @ErrorLog
EXEC master..sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Recovery of database', @DBName

SELECT TOP 5
     [LogDate]
    ,SUBSTRING([TEXT], CHARINDEX(') is ', [TEXT]) + 4,CHARINDEX(' complete (', [TEXT]) - CHARINDEX(') is ', [TEXT]) - 4) AS PercentComplete
    ,CAST(SUBSTRING([TEXT], CHARINDEX('approximately', [TEXT]) + 13,CHARINDEX(' seconds remain', [TEXT]) - CHARINDEX('approximately', [TEXT]) - 13) AS FLOAT)/60.0 AS MinutesRemaining
    ,CAST(SUBSTRING([TEXT], CHARINDEX('approximately', [TEXT]) + 13,CHARINDEX(' seconds remain', [TEXT]) - CHARINDEX('approximately', [TEXT]) - 13) AS FLOAT)/60.0/60.0 AS HoursRemaining
    ,[TEXT]

FROM @ErrorLog ORDER BY [LogDate] DESC
```

See also [Why does database recovery take so long?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126711/why-does-database-recovery-take-so-long/126712#126712)

Comment: Thank you Shanky for the link. I read that while we were having this issue. It was very useful.